# Dispatch doesn't update my components in Redux

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update a table right after the user updates some values in a row. While testing if it was working I saw that sometimes redux dispatch the action but sometimes it doesn't and I can't understand why.

```
axios.post(`${URL}/react/update`, JSON.stringify(foo))
  .then(() => {
    dispatch(fooActions.getFoos());
  })
  .catch(e => console.log('error'));
```

I also tried using fetch but it gives me the same problem, sometimes updates but sometimes it doesn't. In `getFoos()` I simply make another call to another URL. Also checking the data sent in the update I see that it is all right since it also updates my DB.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any error in cconsole

Comment: Nop, I only saw in the redux console that the action is not dispatched

Comment: Make sure that immutability is taken into account, whenever you are updating the state, make sure to create a new object - also remember the same for nested objects.
you can use Object.assign to create the new object.

Comment: in the getFoos() I update the store to get the updated data from the db so I have the store in the same state (pun not intended) as the db.